# Certain commands in vimrc not being picked up anymore

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I am having an issue where anything I enter into my `.vimrc` file is not being picked up, regardless of how many times I add it / close the file / re-open it, etc. Here is the most basic example of what I came up with: https://gyazo.com/ae18bd40f4dec269fb36d723865d5efe.

As you can see, entering in

```
inoremap    xxx1 hello
```

Into my `vimrc` file does absolutely nothing. However, as soon as I type that command in directly it works just fine. So, what might be going on here? (Note that some commands I have in my `vimrc` file from previous **do** work.

Note the above command has been in my vimrc file for days, so the question isn't asking about how to refresh an already-opened vimrc file, but basically why the commands there aren't being recognized anymore.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! The vimrc file is only read during Vim startup. So updating it and saving it doesn't make Vim re-read the commands... You can use a command such as `:so %` (short for `:source %` where `%` means the current file) to make Vim re-read it, maybe that's what you're looking for?

Comment: @filbranden of course. I was doing that. Also saving it and re-opening the file to make sure everything is being re-loaded.

Comment: @filbranden updated the question for clarity!

Comment: Are you sure that's your actual vimrc file? In Linux/Unix the file path is `~/.vimrc` with a `.` at the beginning of the name. In Windows it's `_vimrc`. Is it in your home directory? You can actually use `:e $MYVIMRC` to edit the actual file (assuming it exists.)

Comment: @filbranden yes, thank you!! Oh that was driving me crazy thanks so much for that note. Not sure why I add an extra file named `vimrc` in the `.vim` directory. Want to post it as an answer?

Comment: Ah! The `~/.vim/vimrc` file is a valid file path... But if the `~/.vimrc` file exists, it takes priority. Yes, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some discussion in the comments, it turns out that the vimrc file you were editing was the `~/.vim/vimrc` file. But the `~/.vimrc` file takes priority when it exists. So Vim was ignoring your `~/.vim/vimrc` because it was being shadowed by the existing `~/.vimrc` file.

As a solution, either keep using `~/.vimrc` exclusively, or migrate all its contents to `~/.vim/vimrc` and remove that file completely.

See [`:help .vimrc`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#.vimrc):

> Five places are searched for initializations. **The first that exists is used, the others are ignored.**  The `$MYVIMRC` environment variable is set to the file that was first found, [...]
>
> 1. [...]
> 2. The user vimrc file(s):
>
> - `$HOME/.vimrc`         (for Unix) (*)
> - `$HOME/.vim/vimrc`     (for Unix) (*)
> - ...